# stopping form validation on error

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm new to html and JS. I have a problem with stopping my form before it gets sent to another static site when there is an error. All of my validation works but even if there are errors it still redirects to the other site. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to code a if statement on "action" or on the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 8 Lab - JavaScript DOM and Arrays</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<script>
     function validate()
    {
        var fName =document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value//firstname validation
        if(fName==null || fName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
        }


        var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if(lName==null || lName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a last name.";
        }


        var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if(address==null || address=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML= "Please enter an address.";
        }


        var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if(city==null || city=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML= "Please enter a city.";
        }


        var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if(postalCode.value.match(pCodeCheck))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML= "Please enter a valid postal code.";
        }

                    // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items
        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if(itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if(itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if(itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
        }

                    //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if(wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML= "You must order atleast one item.";
        }





    }
</script>

    <h2>Order Form</h2> <!-- action="processForm.html"      "javascript:void(0)" -->
    <form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="validate();" action="processForm.html" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Personal Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="firstNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="lastNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
            <td id="addressError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30"></td>
            <td id="cityError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Province:</td>
            <td><select name="province" id="province" size="1">
                    <option disabled>Select a province</option>
                    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="QC">Québec</option>
                    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                    <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                    <option value="NWT">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Postal Code:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" maxlength="6"></td>
            <td id="postalCoderror"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Order Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Select your products:<br>
            <td>Widget #1&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget1qty" id="widget1qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$5.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #2&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget2qty" id="widget2qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$15.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #3&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget3qty" id="widget3qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$25.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="itemQTY"></td>
        </tr>
        <th colspan="3"></th><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Shipping Type:</td>
            <td>Standard ($5.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeStandard" value="Standard" checked></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Express ($10.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeExpress" value="Express"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Overnight ($20.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeOvernight" value="Overnight"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Submit Order</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="validate();" value="Submit Order"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset Form"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the validation, add `return false;` in your conditions with error, this will stop the submit if there is an error, like this for exemple:

```
var fName =document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value//firstname validation
if(fName==null || fName=="")
{
    document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript method, validate, to return a value.  Return true, if the fields are valid, return false, if not.  That will prevent your form from submitting.